# Can't make sense why ConnectionError: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: sql-server, windows, odbc, tedious

I need to process data from an internal SQL Server database using NodeJs (version 20.*). Connection to the database has to use Windows Authentication, thus I opted for the Tedious `mssql` and the `msnodesqlv8` packages, since Tedious alone does not support it.

The minimal functioning Typescript code to get a connection pool is

```
import mssql, {type config as Config} from 'mssql/msnodesqlv8';

const baseConfig: Partial<Config> = {
  database: 'XX',
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true,
  },
};

export const getPool = async () => {
  const server = `xxxx01.subdom.dom.priv`;

  const p = new mssql.ConnectionPool({...baseConfig, server});
  await p.connect();

  return p;
};
```

The above code works fine from my Mac Book Pro workstation with `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` installed.

But when executed on a Windows 2019 Server, it fails with an error

> ConnectionError: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Yet on that very Windows server I was able to

- use Azure Data Studio to connect to the database using the same user and connection parameter
- use ODBC Data Source Administrator to define and test successfully system data-sources in both 32 and 64 bits (using `ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server` which is the standard version on our servers)

I have tried many variations of the above code (as connection strings, specifying `driver`, `instance`, adding the port number without success or even some change in the error message.

I tried to use tracing from the ODBC Data Source Administrator but can't make much sense out of it

Please advise